# How to take the data from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 
regions

```
| region_id | region_name|
|------------------------|
|  1        | zxc        |
|  2        | da         |
|  3        | asdas      |
```

and cities

```
| region_id | city_name  | city_id |
|------------------------|---------|
|  1        | zxc        |    22   |
|  1        | da         |     3   |
|  1        | asdas      |    23   |
|  2        | zxc        |    22   |
|  2        | da         |     3   |
|  1        | asdas      |    23   |
|  3        | zxc        |    22   |
|  3        | da         |     3   |
|  3        | asdas      |    23   |
```

the main column is region_id...others EXACTLY NOW are nothing

the query is:

```
SELECT 
city.name AS city_name,
region.name AS region_name
FROM city 
LEFT JOIN region 
ON (city.region_id = region.region_id) 
ORDER BY region_name
```

So... I get smth. like this:

```
| region_name   | city_name  | city_id |
|---------------|------------|---------|
|  asd          | zxc        |    22   |
|  asd          | da         |     3   |
|  asd          | asdas      |    23   |
|  asd          | zxc        |    22   |
|  asd          | da         |     3   |
|  zxc          | asdas      |    23   |
|  zxc          | zxc        |    22   |
|  zxc          | da         |     3   |
```

Now...do you see a lot of "asd" and "zxc"... so is it okay ? because I need to show the region_name as the title of the block, but the names of the cities must be IN this block, for example:

asd: asdas.zxc.da. and so on...?

can you help me to improve this query?
or if it is ok with it, how can I take the region name only once?

Thank you! good luck!

Comment: @Shawn I need to take the name of region only once, but if I write echo $region['region_name'] it will write it so many times as there are cities, maybe I can improve the query?

Comment: The query is fine. It shows each region a city is in. A way to possibly make it less would be something like a group_concat on the region_name?

Comment: Something like SELECT region_name, GROUP_CONCAT(city_name)

Comment: If thats what your looking for ill make it an official answer.

Comment: @Shawn, I wrote this SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(city.name,city.city_id),region.name AS region_name FROM city LEFT JOIN region ON (city.region_id = region.region_id)

Comment: @Shawn, but it shows me only one row (but there are a lot of regions)

Comment: Wait there might be a bigger thing here. Why the left join? Just noticed that. Looks like join (same as INNER JOIN) might be waht you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44830/discussion-between-shawn-and-costa-rassco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to group by region and then you can concat the city names together:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(city.name,city.city_id),region.name AS region_name
FROM city 
LEFT JOIN region 
ON (city.region_id = region.region_id)
GROUP BY region.name;
```